# Set environment variables necessary for program, programatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

The project I'm working on requires the GDAL library, with skipping all the stuff, has a bit of complicated installation as they're C-bindings for Java. Anyways I did find a relatively easy precompiled version of it, the only thing is it requires the user to set some environment variables.

That's easy enough to do, but the process can still confuse some people so to keep it simple I want like a simple "setup.bat" that will do that for you in Windows. This is what I got so far:

```
set "root=%~dp0"
set "gdalpath=%root%gdal-x64-11.1\"

setx PATH "%PATH%;%gdalpath%"
setx GDAL_DATA "%gdalpath%gdal-x64-11.1\gdal-data\"
setx GDAL_DRIVER_PATH "%gdalpath%gdal-x64-11.1\gdalplugins\"
setx PROJ_LIB "%gdalpath%gdal-x64-11.1\projlib\"
```

It works mostly pretty well except for `PATH`. There's two `PATH`s it seems, one for system and one for user environment variables. Simply calling straight `%PATH%` gives all of them combined, but writing with `setx PATH` writes it all to the user `PATH`.

For example if the variables looked like this before:

[image: before]

After running the batch file they look like this:

[image: after]

Which in this example does conserve the "C:\PHP\" and add the GDAL path at the end, but it just looks messy. I mean I think it more or less works and does what it's supposed to, but I'd rather have it more cleanly. So is there a way to grab only the user PATH variables and append to that?

Comment: If possible, use `pathman` rather than `setx`.  `pathman` is specifically designed for manipulating PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Did you type `setx /?` for pages of help before posting (like /k switch)? Plus setx doesn't do the current console window.

To test if file is already in the path

```
@echo off
echo. 
echo PathFind - Finds the first file in in a path
echo ======== = ===== === ===== ==== == == = ====
echo. 
echo Searching for %1 in %path%
echo. 
set a=%~$PATH:1
If "%a%"=="" (Echo %1 not found) else (echo %1 found at %a%)
```

To read the registry.

```
@for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%A in ('Reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v AlwaysShowMenus') do @if "%%A"=="0x1" echo Matches

Pause
```

User permanent variables are stored here.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

VBScript WSH gives far more fine grained access to the environment.

From Help.

The Environment property contains the WshEnvironment object (a collection of environment variables). If strType is supplied, it specifies where the environment variable resides with possible values of System, User, Volatile, or Process.

The following code retrieves the system environment variable NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS.

Visual Basic Script  Copy Code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM")

WScript.Echo WshSysEnv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")
```

Comment: Nope but the problem doesn't seem to be setting it, it's that calling %PATH% in that line to append to it returns the whole thing for both user and system. I'm not experienced with batch coding so I guess what I'm asking is if there's a way to call the current PATH value but only bring up the values set for the user and not system.

Comment: No. But you can read/write the registry. See answer as I'll post some code.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like direct access to the registry is denied in this work computer since the read part prints "Access Denied" but I think I'm on the right track now. A VBScript may be the better way to do it.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/12/29/how-to-read-user-and-system-variables-using-vbscript.aspx for sample code setting a variable.